# IE8/IE7/IE6/IE5 on Windows XP Use The Wrong Certificate

Tags: ssl, internet-explorer-8, windows-xp, certificate, ssl-certificate

For some reason **IE8 / IE7 / IE6 / IE5** on Windows XP, instead to use the certificate that is listed on the Nginx website config, is using another certificate that is used for other websites.

Checking the Nginx config file for the website everything is fine. A confirm of this is that all the other browsers (Chrome/Firefox/Safari/IE9) are using the correct certificate.

This is the nginx configuration for the app:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name mydomain.com;
    ssl_certificate /root/certs/mydomain.com/mydomain.bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /root/certs/mydomain.com/mydoamin.key;

    access_log /opt/webapps/cs_at/logs/access.log;

    location / {
        add_header P3P 'CP="CAO PSA OUR"';
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:20004;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here the solution:

https://serverfault.com/questions/203574/why-does-ie-think-that-my-certificate-is-invalid
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#sni

**The TLS Server Name Indication extension protocol is not supported on IE8/IE7/IE6 under Windows XP.**

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on this for me? I need to use a unique IP (and therefore server?) for each domain I want to provide a SSL certificate for to be compatible with <=IE8? Is there any solution that doesn't require this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Windows XP/IE 8 system is not recognizing our intermediate files. If you update your Windows system that should fix the issue and allow IE 8 to recognize our intermediate files.

Comment: While all the browsers are using the right certificate, for some reason IE8/IE7/IE6 are using another certificate that is installed on the server and that is issued for another domain.

Comment: As well as updating your XP system you may need to log into the server where the SSL is installed and remove any old/unused SSL certificates.

Comment: I can't remove that certificate, it is used from other apps, by the way we use nginx.

Comment: I am running IE8 inside the XP Mode Virtual Machine and I have all the updates and restarted the machine. Also chrome inside the virtual machine use the right certificate.

Comment: If updating the virtual machine didn't work the issue may be with the server.  Check your server settings and you may want to try reinstalling the intermediate certificate on the server.

Comment: the problem is that it is using the wrong the certificate, but I don't know why

Comment: Have you attempted to reinstall the certificate in nginx?  Maybe if you provide you Nginx configuration myself and others on stackoverflow can help you take a look at your setup.